# Chaining Participants creation using REST API

Tags: api, rest, chaining

I'm trying to create an event and chain the participants creation using the REST API from python. My attempt goes like this:

```
import requests

params = {
 "key": "key",
 "api_key": "apikey",
 "json": 1,
 "sequential": 1,
 "entity": "Event",
 "action": "create",
 "title":"Test event",
 "start_date":20181005123600,
 "event_type_id":"Conference",
 "api.Participant.create": {"event_id":"$value.id","contact_id":"8","participant_status_id":"2"},
 "api.Participant.create.2": {"event_id":"$value.id","contact_id":"6","participant_status_id":"2"}
}

url = "some_url"
response = requests.post(url, params = params)
```

For some reason the event is created but the participants are not. Could anyone give me a hint about what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM logs if there are any errors?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the CiviCRM server @PradeepNayak

Comment: @JME If you don't have access to the server, it's probably best to stand up a demo server to test against.  It's very difficult to troubleshoot such an issue without access to the logs.